# Unable to create a new remote session (Appium java 13) trying to launch app

Tags: java, appium, android-uiautomator

Here is my code. I am a beginner to Appium and I am using Java version 13 and latest version of Eclipse and Appium and I have tried everything but everytime I am getting below exception:

> FAILED: run
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
>   System info: host: 'LAPTOP-044PA886', ip: '192.168.86.221', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13'
>   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>   remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
>       at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\Team Quality\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
>       at asyncHandler (C:\Users\Team Quality\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'

Here is my code:

```
    public static void run() throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Team Quality\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
//      driver.get("http:\\www.easports.com");

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "818cec5");
        cap.setCapability("platformName","Android");

        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.xxx");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity","com.xxx.xxx.activities.SplashActivity");

        System.out.println("code executed till here");


        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "C:\\Users\\Team Quality\\eclipse-workspace\\Intro\\src\\tkstage.apk");

        System.out.println("code executed till here2");
        //AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver =new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> (new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
        //driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        //driver.get("http://appium.io/");

        try {
            AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

        System.out.println("code executed till here3");
    }
```

Comment: Not sure with the following capability: `MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "818cec5"`, it looks like `UDID`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed that application on your device? if not, provide `app` capability with path to your `.apk` file.
Check your `appPackage` and `appActivity` capabilities once again. You can use Apk Analyzer application to ensure that your values are correct

Answer (score 0):

Is your appPackage and appActivity correct? You can do a adb shell to check it